# Windows logo + left key - something similar for gnome?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, window

Is there a way in Gnome to get the functionality described [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts):

**<kbd>Windows logo key</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>**

Maximize the window to the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you're looking for is called [compiz fusion](http://www.howtoforge.com/enabling-compiz-fusion-on-an-ubuntu-10.10-desktop-nvidia-geforce-8200). This will allow you to set 3D settings and animations, and implement the same functionality with a little tweaking as what Windows 7 has out of the box.